# VS 2022. Why my Intellisence does not work when using C++ 20 modules?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense, c++20

I would like to use the C++ 20 Modules in VS 2022. Unfortunately, I cannot use intellisence, even on a very simple test. I put options as "C++ latest", "Modules", Advanced>>"Compile as C++ module  code".
Unfortunately, there are squiggles at the file beginning, and no intellisence, and no identifiers highlighting. Also, we cannot `import std;` anymore (nor std.core).

```
//Test of modules.
#define MODULES
#ifdef MODULES
    import module1;
#else
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <format>
#endif

std::vector<std::string> vec{"Some", " sentence", " to", " print !"};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::format("Hello World!\n");
    for (auto & str : vec) {
        std::cout << std::format("{}", str);
    }
return 0;
}
```

The file module1.ixx:

```
export module module1;

export import <iostream>;
export import <format>;
export import <string>;
export import <vector>;
export import <deque>;
export import <chrono>;
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing ?
VS and intellisence work perfectly with the `#include` without any problem.

Comment: Does it compile and run fine?

Comment: Yes it compiles and runs ok. The problem is intellisence and identifiers highlighting. On a large program on multiple files it is very difficult to work without them. Also I would like to have a speed increase in compiles time.

Comment: You are missing that VS 2022 is new, by MS standards experimental not too reliable piece of software yet. And so it looks, internal compiler errors, debugger acting oddly. Perhaps in two years it will be either patched or replaced with VS 2023 (that happened with VS 2002/VS 2003). The intellisence in it however has always been worthless and never worked with anything but some toy projects.

Comment: I'm rather "naive" of vendor announces... I regularly try them, I think it's the way to go.

Comment: Intellisense is *not* the compiler. It gets things wrong. Trust the compiler, not your IDE and its guesses about code correctness.

Comment: I fully agree. However these editing tools bring a comfort and an efficiency in coding, that I find essential, in my point of view. Today V17.5 is a huge improvement. Personally I use modules with latest and it is a big improvement, not only in compile speed. MS (in my opinion), has made the right decision to improve STL with C++20, 23 and intellisense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intellisence module support is still experimental.

I tested your code in Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.4.3 and there was no issues.

However, Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.5.0 Preview 2.0 shows a couple of squiggles.

ISO committee(C++23) voted for `import std;` and `import std.compat;`.

To use `import std;` in preview version(17.5.0) you need to add std.ixx file. In my machine, the file is located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32124\modules.

Add the file from Solution Explorer(Add -> existing Item...).

Please, refer to this site for more information.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170

EDIT: As of MSVC 17.6.0 Preview 3.0, it is not necessary to add std.ixx file. The IDE knows how to build. If added it causes compile error.

Comment: Yes I know this page info; however I missed that it was for 17.5.0.  BTW, have you noticed a real increase in compile time ? and the intellisence is it working (suggestions and identifiers highlight ) ?

Comment: [`import std;` is said to be faster to compile.](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3662808/c-plus-plus-23-to-introduce-module-support.html) This is a C++23 feature and MSVC and other vendors are catching up so it is too early to fully utilize standard library module(C++23) as well as modules(C++20).

Comment: You're right. Good recall.

Comment: Done. Yes, hoping 17.5 will come soon :-)